# getting average of multiple column with null data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB table named **score**

All the columns are set to `VARCHAR` as i want to use `null data`, not as `0`

```html
!  id   !  A    !  B   ! avg  !    
-------------------------------
!  01   !  10   !  0   !      !
!  02   !       !  10  !      !
!  03   !   0   !  10  !      !
!  04   !  10   !      !      !
```

I want to get the average from that table like this

```
! avg !    
-------
!  5  !
!  10 !
!  5  !
!  10 !
```

Which **SQL** command(s) do i need to use to achieve the above result

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (COALESCE(A, 0) + COALESCE(B, 0)) /
       ((CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        (CASE WHEN B IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) AS avg
FROM score
```

**Note:**

I did not handle the case of division by zero.